# Using a graph, analyse the evolution of the quality of the catalogue content over time

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to :

Analyze the evolution of the quality of the catalogue content over time with a graph (seaborn or matplotlib).

I've tried this but I don't know why this doesn't show me the average rating notes (6.8, 5.3...)

```
plt.figure(figsize = (50,50))
plt.plot_date(x = df['averageRating'].values, y = df['release_year'].values, xdate = True, ls = '-');
```

Comment: You need `ydate = True` instead of xdate since you put the dates in y. Actually you probably want xdate but in this case set `x = df['release_year'].values, y = df['averageRating'].values`.

Comment: Sort the data before plotting or use linestyle = "none" to avoid the chaotic looking graph

Comment: I have replaced ```ydate = True`` in place of xdate. I now have the dates 1975-07-01 in x and y and still not my notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `x = df['averageRating'].values, y = df['release_year'].values, xdate = True`, but the x-axis is not a date value. Use `ydate = True` and `xdate = False`, or switch the x and y values.

If matplotlib doesn't sort the values, sort the values before plotting or remove the lines with `linestyle = "none", marker = "x"` (see documentation for [lines](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) and [markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html)).

Comment: I removed the line linestyle = ''none'' I now have a series of dots which is more presentable but does not solve the problem of my x and y

Comment: @kevincaro I found that you might also need to set `xdate = False`

Comment: Thank you that corrected my graph, do you know how I could display only the years instead of 1975-06-15... ?

Comment: @kevincaro the ratings (59345, 47618, etc) were converted to days or seconds since `1970-01-01`, by pandas I think. (Also please use English here, my French is atrocious)

Comment: hahah sorry, is it possible to change the display by putting for example only the years? or ranges like 1975 to 1980, 1980 to 1985?

Comment: If you only want years, using a normal `plt.plot` with only years as y-values might work, matplotlib might also have some options (take a look a the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-format)